# Action Filter is not working in asp.net core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I have created an action filter for HTTP request validation in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API.

Unfortunately it is not working. The problem has to be at controller level, because the same works in .NET Framework.

**CustomAuthorize.cs**

```cs
public class CustomAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public CustomAuthorize(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        string secrect = _configuration.GetSection("AuthJWT").GetSection("Secrect").Value;
        var request = context.Request.Headers.GetValues("AuthJWT").FirstOrDefault();
        //Add Validation code here
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomAuthorize))]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{       
    [HttpGet("getdata")]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        return Ok("Success");
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorize>();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: we need to see the complete code for the filter and the validation code at least the relevant portion....

Comment: also how is it "not working"... we need to be able to reproduce this.  so you need to post enough code and information for a fully reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionFilterAttribute abstract class includes the following methods to override:

```
void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Use `ActionExecutingContext` in `OnActionExecuting`.

Only need to modify `OnActionExecuting` of `CustomAuthorize`. Other codes are same as u.

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            string secrect = _configuration.GetSection("AuthJWT").GetSection("Secrect").Value;
            
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["AuthJWT"].FirstOrDefault();
            //Add Validation code here
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        }
```

> Test of result

[image]